# unordered_map how it works/optimizing the design?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

I was reading the following post on another forum from a guy who seems to know a lot about C++ internals regarding inserting thousands of keys in to "dictionaries":

> e) Map and Set look-up is done with Red-Black or Balanced Tree's and
> each item is allocated "individually", so if you're allocating 500,000
> Instruments [by symbol] with a pointer to an instrument Object-class
> associated, you have 'N' number of bytes [plus overhead] for the
> string and 4-bytes [plus overhead] for the pointer. And include;
> one-minute, five-second, one-second price time-series on all
> instruments and full trade-history on ALL those Instruments in STD
> Containers. That's a lot of memory and a hell of a lot More Wasted due
> to small object Allocation overhead!
>
> f) Notoriously, STD Map & Set walk thru all of the keys to FIND using LowerBound [Less
> Than Compare] which is slow as hell.
>
> g) Some Genius may say "No, they use an
> Unsorted Map"...well they don't, but even if they did they are STILL
> doing a String Compare on a discretely allocated element.
>
> What I do in C++ is the following (example);
>
> a) Create a "custom" in-place String Class-object, which has two
> personalities; a) a Byte array, and b) an Integer array [of Modulus 4
> and Aligned on the Native Boundary]. b) Use Custom Map & Set, which
> are Hash based in 2x Dimensions with Nodes allocated in a Flat
> Contiguous Memory region [which may & can dynamically re-size]. c)
> String [in Integer format] Hashing is done by Integer to pipeline the
> CPU and Key Comparison is done similarly.
>
> With these techniques, which can only be done in C++, C or ASM there
> are at least 4-5x ORDERS OF MAGNITUDE the performance of the same
> thing done in .NET, C# or Java.

http://www.elitetrader.com/vb/showthread.php?s=1eb70fb998d8a51d22050ea53d24db21&threadid=204368&perpage=6&pagenumber=3

If I know roughly how many keys I will be inserting, what techniques are there which I could use to design my own unordered_map implementation which is more efficient than the standard one for my particular usage?

(any 101s about designing hash functions are most welcome)

Comment: Wow. Especially f). So, instead of a long answer: Just don't listen to that guy. Choose the right STL containers for your task, but don't write your own custom classes upfront without even knowing if or where you have a performance problem.

Comment: Do you know the range of the keys?

Comment: @Anycorn when you say "range" what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use a `unordered_map` You just have to design a **hash function for your key**. C++ standard library provide a set of hash function for in-built key types like: `hash<int>` or `hash<float>`.
If you decleare a `unordered_map<int,int>` it'll by default use `hash<int>` as it's hash function. **But if you want to use your own object as key, you have to provide your own hash function**.

---

Advantages:
Although the insertion time in a `unordered_map<T>` is larger but hashing generally provides a `O(1)` complexity when retrieving a `(key,value)` pair from the container.

Comment: It doesn't if two keys map to the same hask bucket- then it reverts ot O(n) because each bucket is a list?

Comment: Okey, I'm adding the word "generally"

Comment: ["Search, insertion, and removal have average constant-time complexity."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) -- there are ways to handle collisions.  If your hashing function matches the requirements, `unordered_map` must be implemented in such a way that either collisions are not that expensive, or that they are exceedingly rare.  For a hash function, you can use `boost`s hash-combiner, then do a chain-combined hash of the individual characters in the string.  A class that pre-stores its hash used carefully can also boost performance.